# how to return current working directory from function?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

has experience with high level programming languages. I read the Rust book and now trying to survive and understand how the "things" in Rust works. I would love that someone explain what the heck is - Ok(()) and how to deal with it? My goal is to return result from function in to the variable where the output:

```
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.01s
     Running `target/debug/rcp ./file/ aba`
Ok(
    "/home/tomand/rcp",
)
```

Here is the full code:

```
use std::fs;
use std::env;
use serde_json;
use regex::Regex;
use std::path::Path;

fn determinate_file_size(file: &str) -> u64 {
    fs::metadata(file).unwrap().len()
}

fn determinate_is_it_file_or_dirctory(arg: &str) -> &str {
    let file = "File";
    let dir = "Directory";
    let re = Regex::new(r"/").unwrap();
    if re.is_match(arg) {
        return dir;
    }
    return file;
}

fn collect_user_arguments() -> Vec<String> {
    env::args().collect()
}

fn check_if_arguments_count_valid(args: &Vec<String>) -> bool {
    if args.len() == 3 {
        return true
    }
    help();
    return false
}

fn get_current_working_dir() -> Result<T> {
    env::current_dir()
}

fn help() {
    println!("Examples:");
    println!("rcp [srcfile] [destfile]");
    println!("rcp [srcdir]/[srcfile] [destdir]/[destfile]");
}


fn main() {
    let WORKING_DIR = get_current_working_dir();
    let args: Vec<String> = collect_user_arguments();

    if check_if_arguments_count_valid(&args) {
        let arg1 = &args[1];
        let arg2 = &args[2];
        println!("{:#?}", determinate_is_it_file_or_dirctory(&arg1));
    }
}
```

Seems the compiler tried to give me some inspiration but eventually we miscommunicate in the end:

```
error[E0107]: this enum takes 2 generic arguments but 1 generic argument was supplied
   --> src/main.rs:42:33
    |
42  | fn get_current_working_dir() -> Result<T> {
    |                                 ^^^^^^ - supplied 1 generic argument
    |                                 |
    |                                 expected 2 generic arguments
```

EDIT:
I went with this approach:

```
fn get_current_working_dir() -> String {
    let res = env::current_dir();
    match res {
        Ok(path) => path.into_os_string().into_string().unwrap(),
        Err(_) => "FAILED".to_string()
    }
}
```

It seems more practice is required to understand the **Result** type and how to manage it.

Comment: Not sure what your issue is. I put your code in the playground, removed the `println!` around `env.current_dir()`, and it told me that the return type was `Result<PathBuf, std::io::Error>`. Put that as the function's return type (as useless as that function seems to be) and things worked out.

Comment: That aside `Result<T>` makes no sense on mutliple levels: one, while several modules "partially apply" one of the parameters to have their own result (e.g. `std::io::Result<T>` which is an alias to `std::result::Result<T, std::io::Error>`) that's not the case of the main `Result` type; and second `<T>` in a free function means the caller has to provide the type *somehow*, which it has no opportunity for here, `current_dir()` is not generic in any way.

Comment: "Not sure what your issue is."... people become so arrogant when they're understand everything, forgetting there's also newbies...

Comment: they will never think in the perspective of newbie lol

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[`std::env::current_dir`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.current_dir.html#) returns a `std::io::Result<Pathbuf>`, so you need to use that type in your wrapper method:

```rust
fn get_current_working_dir() -> std::io::Result<PathBuf> {
    env::current_dir()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f525b0348c7b7939c520b23f833641b3)

Other nitpick:

`const` is not a type so `let WORKING_DIR: const = get_current_working_dir();` is wrong, just `let WORKING_DIR = get_current_working_dir();` is enough.